# Skype not detecting webcam and microphone, while Audacity does

Tags: sound, skype, webcam, microphone

I have a Logitech Quickcam Vision Pro (Quickcam Pro 9000) and Skype doesn't detect it.
When I start `pavucontrol`, the only place I can find the microphone is in "Configuration", where it is listed as:

> QuickCam Vision Pro
>   Profile: Analog Mono Input

It is not visible in the input device list:

[image: Screenshot]

Audacity does see the microphone as:

> USB Device 0x46d:0x9a6: Audio(hw:2,0): FrontMic:0

Skype only sees PulseAudio in Options -> Audio.

My Xubuntu version is: 14.04, Kernel: 3.13.0-45-generic.